# Writing specific lines of a text file

Tags: python

I write this code:

```
f = open('example.txt','r')
lines = f.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(f):
if i < 3:
   lines = ['LC '+line for line in lines]
   with open('./example.txt', 'w') as f:
      f.writelines(lines)
      f.close()
elif i < 5:
    lines = ['LB '+line for line in lines]
    with open('./example.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
        f.close()
elif i > 6:
    break

 f.close()
```

I have a file with 11 lines. I want to write something in the start from every line. The word is different for the 3 first line and different for other 2. Could you help me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"I want to write something in the start from every line."* I find this specification to vague. Can you say more exactly both what you want to do and what you are getting now?

Comment: @dmckee in the first 3 line the word LC and in the other line the word LB. I am getting trouble in statement if < 3

Comment: @user1617766 the body of your for loop needs to be indented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lines = [("LC" if i < 3 else "LB")+line for i,line in enumerate(lines)]
```

might do the trick

Comment: `[("LC%d"%i)+line for i,line in enumerate(lines)]`

Answer (score 1):

for `lines = ['LC '+line for line in lines]`

you are writing `LC` to every line not just the first 3 lines.

`lines = ['LB '+line for line in lines]` same thing here

First you can add the proper prefixes to the lines, THen afterwards you can actually write the lines.
Somethign like:

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
  if i < 3:
     # add prefix to line
  if 3 < i < 5:
     # add correct prefix
```

now your lines have the proper prefixes you can write all of them to a file

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your second conditional is a little messed up. If you're writing something on the first three lines, then something for the 4th and 5th, then your conditional needs to be changed.

Try changing the second elif to:

```
elif i <= 5 and i >=3:
```

Also, a word of a advice, you don't need to open the file for writing each time. You can set the first line to:

```
f = open('example.txt','rw')
```

This opens the file, gives you a handle to it, and allows you to read and write to it.